# Is struggling from a disease to remain committed on the path of God "greater jihad"?

Tags: jihad

I am suffering from ADHD and I am also autistic. I can be called intelligent but I struggle a lot on personal and mental level due to these problems. My mind is like a fire cracker, new and sometimes absurd thoughts spurt out of it occasionally. Its difficult for me to switch my mind off. Some of those thoughts can be considered religious impropriety. I feel very ashamed and become frantic when these kinds of thoughts come to my mind, but I however struggle a lot to remain a committed Muslim and have deepest reverence for Allah. However, I fear that having these thoughts are a disrespect to Allah and that breaks me. I would like to be a devoted follower of Islam with deepest reverence for Allah, devoid of any such frivolities and believe one day I just might.

Nonetheless, is my struggle "greater jihad"? Will these thought offend Allah? Will he be angry or abandon me for having these thoughts which are rather out of my control and not intentional?

Also are there any "words" I can say, which can help me with this problem? For example, when I have evil thoughts for others, I rhyme "There is no power other than Allah, Allah Uh-Akbar" and most of those times these thoughts stop.

P.S I have recently converted without knowledge of my family and they are an ardent opposer of Islam, thus neither can I offer namaz nor fast in ramadan(I live with them), though I very much want to. Also, I don't know Arabic, so please prefer English translations.

Comment: This is not a peer support website, Pesla, and you're question may be soon deleted although your title question makes it valid I think. But as for your specific problem [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16418726#16418726) I left you a message which may help you.

Comment: @infatuated Oh ok. The islamic medicine, I am looking into it. Any remarks on the second part of second para? Also are you aware of any "words" reciting whom might bring stasis to my mind? In those hard moments should I ask Allah for help?

Comment: Check the link again.

Comment: We are all human. Everybody sometimes has thoughts that they cannot control. If you work hard to try to quickly think about something else, that can surely be considered a good thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer to your title:** *YES*

**Detailed Answer:**

I won't say it would be considered as greater jihad, although there were some narrations from some companions that state:"fighting oness self is considered greater Jihad" but staying patient while struggling can increase your deeds and hopefully lead to Jannah.

As in the hadith in [Sahih Bukhary and Musli](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/1/35):

> 'Ata' bin Abu Rabah reported:
>   Ibn 'Abbas (May Allah be pleased with them) asked him whether he would like that he should show him a woman who is from the people Jannah. When he replied that he certainly would, he said, "This black woman, who came to the Prophet (ﷺ) and said, 'I suffer from epilepsy and during fits my body is exposed, so make supplication to Allah for me.' He (ﷺ) replied: 'If you wish you endure it patiently and you be rewarded with Jannah, or if you wish, I shall make supplication to Allah to cure you?' She said, 'I shall endure it.' Then she added: 'But my body is exposed, so pray to Allah that it may not happen.' He (Prophet (ﷺ)) then supplicated for her".

*Thus, fighting these improper thoughts and staying patient may hopefully increase your deeds iA*

As for the improper thoughts, it was already mentioned in a [hadith in sahih Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/1/250) that you can say this statement to help get rid of improper thoughts:

> It is narrated on the authority of Abu Huraira that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said:
>   Men will continue to question one another till this is propounded: Allah created all things but who created Allah? He who found himself confronted with such a situation should say: I affirm my faith in Allah.

So what the hadith say, when you have such improper thoughts, it is Ok. Every muslim has these thoughts. just say: "I affirm my faith in Allah." and go on with your life. Do something which can keep you busy from overthinking.

Comment: Thank you sohaeb for mentioning the fact I am not alone. Your answer clears a lot of doubts, one thing I would like to mention, credit goes to @infatuated is saying Astaghfirullah(I seek forgiveness from Allah) more than hundred times daily has had a wonderful effect on me. If anyone reads this, I would like to bring it to their knowledge that it's what Prophet Muhammad(PBUH) used to do daily.