# Will someone be punished for having improper thoughts about God?

Tags: halal-haram, punishment, evil-thoughts

My brother recently confessed that he sometimes has improper thoughts (some are really bad) for Allah. My brother is mentally unfit and having those thoughts brings him fear (he drenches in fear) and he repents but he is afraid he cannot stop them. Bear in mind, these thoughts spurt out in his mind, they are not intentional. He says *ishtighfar* 133 times daily which have been helpful in bringing peace, but have not been able to stop those thoughts from coming. He is a good person, charitable and sorts.

Will he be punished for these thoughts? Is there anything than can be done to purify his mind? Is he being tested? Will Allah punish someone for sins committed he cannot control?

Answer (score 1):

**I will quote part of my answer from [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/14976/885):**

> As for the improper thoughts, it was already mentioned in a [hadith in
>   sahih Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/1/250) that you can say this statement to help you get rid of
>   improper thoughts:
>
> > It is narrated on the authority of Abu Huraira that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: Men will continue to question one another till this is
> >     propounded: Allah created all things but who created Allah? He who
> >     found himself confronted with such a situation should say: I affirm my
> >     faith in Allah.
>
> So what the hadith say, when you have such improper thoughts, it is
>   Ok. Every muslim has these thoughts. just say: "I affirm my faith in
>   Allah." and go on with your life. Do something which can keep you busy
>   from overthinking.